# How to write/optimize sql query that need to select data from 6 related tables until it get what it need

Tags: php, mysql, query-performance

I am writing PHP application built on MySQL database made for 5-6 application sharing it. Because of that, I can not alter database structure, and I know many of you will say to do that first, but unfortunately I can't.

Here is my SQL fiddle of database schema, query that I am using, and desired output:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de7493/1

My solution is working on this example database, but on real production one, where some of these tables have more than 1m rows, when I try to run it my DB crash. Even if I cut down this sql to select only from 3-4 tables it will still crash. Maybe this is not possible to do, maybe I am doing it wrong. Here is what I have to do:

I am dynamically getting cpv_id from url. In my example, cpv_id is 66113000. Based on that value, I have to discover which club offers are related with that cpv_id. Then based on those offers I have to discover which club members are having some of those offers. ( club members are companies ). Then based on club member id, I have to discover some informations about company that is a member of the club, among that data I have to discover company special_id. And based on that special_id I have to read company reports.

So basically: based on cpv_id I have to discover company reports for the company having club offers related to that id ( simple right ? ). As you can see from the way my tables are related in SQLFiddle, I need to get through 6 tables to get what I really need. Once again, I can not alter database structure.

This is very complex thing going on, I am afraid that you will not understand what I need. I hope that SQLFiddle will help. And if you have any more questions please ask me.

So considering that my solution, my query, fail since database crash if I run it. Is there any way to get desired result ? Can I optimize this query somehow, or do I need to write some other one, or do anything else ? I am pretty lost, since I never had to go this deep and read data from so many tables just to get desired result.

Thanks,
Anita

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the same thing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_report.* 
FROM company_report, 
     company, 
     users, 
     club, 
     club_offer, 
     club_offer_cpv  
WHERE company_report.company_special_id = company.special_id AND 
      company.id = users.company_id AND
      users.id = club.users_id AND
      club.id = club_offer.club_id AND
      club_offer.id = club_offer_id AND
      club_offer_cpv.cpv_id = 66113000
```

Other people will prefer joins, but I find this easier to read, and they are equivalent. It would look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_report.* 
FROM company_report
JOIN company        ON company_report.company_special_id = company.special_id 
JOIN users          ON company.id = users.company_id 
JOIN club           ON users.id = club.users_id
JOIN club_offer     ON club.id = club_offer.club_id
JOIN club_offer_cpv ON club_offer.id = club_offer_id AND
                       club_offer_cpv.cpv_id = 66113000
```

Actually, that's not bad, I mean I might even prefer this last one.

Comment: That's exactly how I'd do it. Only thing I'd add is using [MySQL's EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html) in the event that still takes forever, as there is probably a busted, or non-existent index(s).

Comment: Yes, you need proper indexing. It seems to work fine in the SQLFiddle.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try these solutions tomorrow on production server with real db, I hope it will work. Wish me luck :D

Comment: I have extended this question with new requests. Can you please check it out ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794767/how-to-do-two-mysql-sums-based-on-different-criterias Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add index to your table relationships id's, then try to add one by one table using left outer joins