# How to do two MySQL SUMs based on different criterias

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sum

I have 6 tables related to each other. I have a JOIN query gathering all data. I am starting by providing cpv_id as a variable coming from users, and then at the end I need to get reports for each company that is related to that cpv_id ( through many tables between them ).

Basically, this is the flow:

I get **cpv_id** from users, I find it in **club_offer_cpv** table and I get *club_offer_id* so I can connect to **club_offer** table. Then in **club_offer** table I get *club_id* so I can connect to **club** table. Then in **club** table I get *users_id* so I can connect to **users** table. Then in **users** table I get *company_id* so I can connect to **company** table. In **company** table I get *special_id* so I can connect to the last table **company_reports**. This is where I need to get my data from. And I need this:

Here I have 3 field of interest: **report_year**, **variable_code** and **variable_value**.

**report_year** stores the year when company report was made.
**variable_code** stores the type of report that was made. In my simplified example on SQL Fiddle, possible values are **AOP 605** and **AOP 201**.
**variable_value** stores the value for each variable_code. For example for **AOP 605** code there will be value of **5**.

Here comes my trouble: I need to sum variable_value for each variable_code for all companies that belong to some cpv_id group ( came from user request ). I only managed to create query that will sum values for one code. You can see that in SQL Fiddle provided: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3e296/2

In the output you will see that I am doing totalSum for code **AOP 201**, and In my application I am executing one more query to calculate sum for **AOP 605**, but I believe that is not ideal, and probably there is some way to get SUMs for both **AOP 201** and **AOP 605** in the same query. I can call them then sum201 and sum605 and display them both in my application. Can someone please tell me if this is possible ? Can you show me the query that will collect sums for **AOP 201** and **AOP 605** and store them in separate values so I can display sum for **AOP 201** and sum for **AOP 605** ???

Also there is one more tricky part. As you can see in my query I am having this condition: `AND company_report.report_year = 2013`. This is not ideal, because some companies will not have reports made in 2013, some of them have only for 2012. I would have to take whatever is the last year of report that they have. So for example if some company have reports in 2012 and 2013, I will take only 2013 in count. Similarly, if some other company have reports for 2009 and 2012, I will take only 2012 in count.

Can you help me with this also ?

I am struggling with this for 3 day now, and can not find solution. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I need sums of **AOP 605** and **AOP 201** as seprate columns, so I can access them in my application code like $sumOne - displays the sum for **AOP 605** and $sumTwo - displays the sum for **AOP 201**.

**MORE INFO**: I am trying to merge these two queries into one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_report.*, floor(sum(variable_value)) as totalSum
                                         FROM company_report
                                         JOIN company        ON company_report.special_id = company.special_id 
                                         JOIN users          ON company.id = users.company_id 
                                         JOIN club           ON users.id = club.users_id
                                         JOIN club_offer     ON club.id = club_offer.club_id
                                         JOIN club_offer_cpv ON club_offer.id = club_offer_id 
                                                             AND club_offer_cpv.cpv_id LIKE '66%'
                                                             AND company_report.variable_code = 'AOP 201'
                                                             AND company_report.report_year = 2013
```

AND

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_report.*, floor(sum(variable_value)) as totalSum
                                         FROM company_report
                                         JOIN company        ON company_report.special_id = company.special_id 
                                         JOIN users          ON company.id = users.company_id 
                                         JOIN club           ON users.id = club.users_id
                                         JOIN club_offer     ON club.id = club_offer.club_id
                                         JOIN club_offer_cpv ON club_offer.id = club_offer_id 
                                                             AND club_offer_cpv.cpv_id LIKE '66%'
                                                             AND company_report.variable_code = 'AOP 605'
                                                             AND company_report.report_year = 2013
```

Please pay attention on these lines in each query:

```
company_report.variable_code = 'AOP 605'

company_report.variable_code = 'AOP 201'
```

So in one query I want to get sum of variable_value for rows having variable_code = "AOP 605", and in second I need to get sum of variable_value for rows having variable_code = "AOP 201". But I am thinking that there must be some way to get both sums in one query, but on the way that I can display them bot separately, like:

Sum of AOP 605 is : 123
Sum of AOP 201 is : 345

Comment: For your first problem you can apply the group by on the `variable_code` and `IN` for join condition. Here is sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3e296/12

Comment: Thank you ! But how can I access sum for AOP 605 and how for AOP 201 ? Shouldn't there be a new field like sum1 having sum for AOP 605 and sum2 having sum for AOP 201 ?

Comment: Current query gives you the each row for the each variabl_code but if you want the column then you can apply the `CASE WHEN variablecode then sum` expression in query.

Comment: Can you please fiddle it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is the GROUP BY part of a SELECT, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_report.*, floor(sum(variable_value)) as totalSum
FROM company_report
JOIN company        ON company_report.special_id = company.special_id 
JOIN users          ON company.id = users.company_id 
JOIN club           ON users.id = club.users_id
JOIN club_offer     ON club.id = club_offer.club_id
JOIN club_offer_cpv ON club_offer.id = club_offer_id 
                    AND club_offer_cpv.cpv_id LIKE '66%' 
                    AND company_report.variable_code IN ('AOP 201','AOP 605')
                    AND company_report.report_year = 2013
GROUP BY company_report.variable_code
```

Is that it?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not :(. I have added further information at the end of the post.

Comment: You are not telling me why? My answer does produce exactly what your two seperate SQL commands do. I tried it in your sqlfiddle. What you added at the end of the post doesn't make sense, in that context. So please explain why you think it is not what you're looking for.

Comment: I can not output in my application: Sum of AOP 605 is : 123
Sum of AOP 201 is : 345. There are more variable_codes than just AOP 605 and AOP 201, but I do not want them in output. Need only sums for these two, and I need them returned as columns. I said above, I made two queries returning sums for each AOP of interest, now I want to merge them into one for performance increase.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well just select on your two variable_codes. I don't know why they should be in a seperate column though. I don't think that's useful or easy to do. I will amend my answer.

Comment: Maybe I do not need them as columns if I can take values returned and add custom text to each of them to get : Sum of AOP 605 is : 123  (new line)
Sum of AOP 201 is : 345

Comment: I have change the answer above, it's now restricted to AOP 605 and AOP 201.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it seems that I can not find a solution to this problem. Your query will return right results, but I can not use  them as I want in my application. You see, the result returned for AOP 201 need to be multiplied with 1000. If I do multiplication on the result returned, both AOP 201 and AOP 605 will be multiplied. Damn :(

Comment: I'm sure you'll find a solution. You've got the data. I don't know where this factor 1000 is coming from, just remember that you don't have to solve everything in SQL, you can do some things in PHP as well.

Comment: Thanks, but it's impossible :(